# Erro com Swagger UI ao implementar em API Node.js - Apenas operações de review.js são exibidas

Tags: node.js, api, swagger

Estou tentando implementar o Swagger UI em minha API Node.js, mas estou enfrentando problemas na exibição das operações corretas para cada rota. No início, recebia o erro "No operations defined in spec!" na página do Swagger UI. Consegui resolver esse problema, mas agora estou enfrentando um novo desafio.

Ao acessar a página do Swagger UI, somente as operações da rota review.js são exibidas, embora eu tenha feito o mesmo processo para as rotas books.js e users.js. O estranho é que quando testo a API usando o Postman, todas as rotas funcionam corretamente.

Estou utilizando o pacote swagger-ui-express e já verifiquei as especificações do Swagger para cada rota. Não encontrei nenhum erro aparente nos arquivos de rota, mas não consigo entender por que somente as operações de review.js estão sendo exibidas.

Estou desenvolvendo a API no Replit e utilizo o Node.js. Abaixo estão os codigos do arquivos de rota e das configurações do Swagger no Replit e o link do replit:

Replit: https://replit.com/@HiaraMaria/LivrosAPI

Agradeço qualquer ajuda para resolver esse problema e entender por que somente as operações da rota review.js estão sendo exibidas no Swagger UI.

```js
///index.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const { usersSpec, booksSpec, reviewsSpec } = require('./swagger'); 
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const booksRouter = require('./routes/books'); 
const reviewsRouter = require('./routes/reviews');
app.use(express.json());

// Middleware para a rota de usuários
app.use('/users/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(usersSpec));

// Middleware para a rota de livros
app.use('/books/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(booksSpec));

// Middleware para a rota de livros
app.use('/reviews/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(reviewsSpec));

// Configuração das rotas
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/books', booksRouter);
app.use('/reviews', reviewsRouter);

// Iniciar o servidor
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor rodando na porta ${port}`);
});

//swagger.js
const swaggerJsdoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');

// Configuração do Swagger para a rota de usuários
const usersOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    openapi: '3.0.0',
    info: {
      title: 'API de Usuários',
      version: '1.0.0',
      description: 'API para gerenciamento de usuários',
    },
    servers: [
      {
        url: 'https://livrosapi.hiaramaria.repl.co', 
      },
    ],
  },
  apis: ['./routes/users.js'], // Caminho para o arquivo de rota de usuários
};

// Configuração do Swagger para a rota de livros
const booksOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    openapi: '3.0.0',
    info: {
      title: 'API de Livros',
      version: '1.0.0',
      description: 'API para gerenciamento de livros',
    },
    servers: [
      {
        url: 'https://livrosapi.hiaramaria.repl.co', 
      },
    ],
  },
  apis: ['./routes/books.js'], // Caminho para o arquivo de rota de livros
};

// Configuração do Swagger para a rota de avaliações/comentários
const reviewsOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    openapi: '3.0.0',
    info: {
      title: 'API de Avaliações/Comentários',
      version: '1.0.0',
      description: 'API para gerenciamento de avaliações e comentários de livros',
    },
    servers: [
      {
        url: 'https://livrosapi.hiaramaria.repl.co',
      },
    ],
  },
  apis: ['./routes/reviews.js'], // Caminho para o arquivo de rota de avaliações/comentários
};

const usersSpec = swaggerJsdoc(usersOptions);
const booksSpec = swaggerJsdoc(booksOptions);
const reviewsSpec = swaggerJsdoc(reviewsOptions);

module.exports = {
  usersSpec,
  booksSpec,
  reviewsSpec,
};

///routes/users.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { usersSpec } = require('../swagger'); 
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');

// Middleware para a rota de documentação do Swagger
router.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(usersSpec));

// Caminho do arquivo JSON
const usersFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../data/dbUsers.json');

// Função para ler os dados do arquivo JSON
const readFromDataUser = () => {
  try {
    const fileData = fs.readFileSync(usersFilePath, 'utf8');
    return JSON.parse(fileData).users;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao ler o arquivo JSON:', error);
    return [];
  }
};

// Carregar os dados do arquivo JSON na inicialização do servidor
let users = readFromDataUser();

/**
 * @swagger
 * /users:
 *   get:
 *     summary: Retorna todos os usuários
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Lista de usuários
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao obter os usuários
 */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Rota GET para obter todos os usuários
  res.json(users);
});


/**
 * @swagger
 * /users/{id}:
 *   get:
 *     summary: Retorna um usuário pelo ID
 *     parameters:
 *       - in: path
 *         name: id
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: integer
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Dados do usuário
 *       404:
 *         description: Usuário não encontrado
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao obter o usuário
 */
// Rota GET para obter um usuário pelo ID
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const user = users.find(u => u.id === parseInt(id));
  if (!user) return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Usuário não encontrado.' });
  res.json(user);
});

/**
 * @swagger
 * /users:
 *   post:
 *     summary: Adiciona um novo usuário
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: true
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               name:
 *                 type: string
 *               email:
 *                 type: string
 *               password:
 *                 type: string
 *     responses:
 *       201:
 *         description: Usuário adicionado com sucesso
 *       400:
 *         description: Nome, email e senha são campos obrigatórios
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao criar senha criptografada
 */
// Rota POST para adicionar um novo usuário
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  if (!name || !email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Nome, email e senha são campos obrigatórios.' });
  }

  try {
    // Gerar o hash da senha
    const saltRounds = 10;
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);

    const newUser = { id: users.length + 1, name, email, password: hashedPassword };
    users.push(newUser);

    // Salvar os dados no arquivo JSON
    fs.writeFile(usersFilePath, JSON.stringify({ users }), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Erro ao salvar os dados no arquivo JSON.', err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao salvar os dados.' });
      }
      console.log('Dados salvos no arquivo JSON com sucesso.');
    });

    res.status(201).json(newUser);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao criar senha criptografada:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao criar senha criptografada.' });
  }
});

/**
 * @swagger
 * /users/{id}:
 *   put:
 *     summary: Atualiza um usuário pelo ID
 *     parameters:
 *       - in: path
 *         name: id
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: integer
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: true
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               name:
 *                 type: string
 *               email:
 *                 type: string
 *               password:
 *                 type: string
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Usuário atualizado com sucesso
 *       404:
 *         description: Usuário não encontrado
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao atualizar o usuário
 */
// Rota PUT para atualizar um usuário pelo ID
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  const user = users.find(u => u.id === parseInt(id));
  if (!user) return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Usuário não encontrado.' });

  // Atualizar os campos de nome e email
  user.name = name || user.name;
  user.email = email || user.email;

  // Atualizar a senha criptografada, caso a senha seja fornecida
  if (password) {
    try {
      const saltRounds = 10;
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
      user.password = hashedPassword;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erro ao criar senha criptografada:', error);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao criar senha criptografada.' });
    }
  }

  // Salvar os dados no arquivo JSON
  fs.writeFile(usersFilePath, JSON.stringify({ users }), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Erro ao salvar os dados no arquivo JSON.', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao salvar os dados.' });
    }
    console.log('Dados salvos no arquivo JSON com sucesso.');
  });

  res.json(user);
});

/**
 * @swagger
 * /users/{id}:
 *   delete:
 *     summary: Remove um usuário pelo ID
 *     parameters:
 *       - in: path
 *         name: id
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: integer
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Usuário removido com sucesso
 *       404:
 *         description: Usuário não encontrado
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao remover o usuário
 */
// Rota DELETE para remover um usuário pelo ID
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  const index = users.findIndex(u => u.id === parseInt(id));
  if (index === -1) return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Usuário não encontrado.' });

  const deletedUser = users.splice(index, 1);

  // Salvar os dados no arquivo JSON
  fs.writeFile(usersFilePath, JSON.stringify(users), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Erro ao salvar os dados no arquivo JSON.', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao salvar os dados.' });
    }
    console.log('Dados salvos no arquivo JSON com sucesso.');
  });

  res.json(deletedUser[0]);
});

module.exports = router;

///routes/books.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// Caminho do arquivo JSON
const booksFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../data/dbBooks.json');

// Função para ler os dados do arquivo JSON
const readDataFromBook = () => {
  try {
    const fileData = fs.readFileSync(booksFilePath, 'utf8');
    return JSON.parse(fileData).books;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao ler o arquivo JSON:', error);
    return [];
  }
};

// Carregar os dados do arquivo JSON na inicialização do servidor
let books = readDataFromBook();

/**
 * @swagger
 * /books:
 *   get:
 *     summary: Obtém todos os livros
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Lista de todos os livros
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao obter os dados
 */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json(books);
});

/**
 * @swagger
 * /books/{id}:
 *   get:
 *     summary: Obtém um livro pelo ID
 *     parameters:
 *       - in: path
 *         name: id
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: integer
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Dados do livro
 *       404:
 *         description: Livro não encontrado
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao obter o livro
 */
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const book = books.find(b => b.id === parseInt(id));
  if (!book) return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Livro não encontrado.' });
  res.json(book);
});

/**
 * @swagger
 * /books:
 *   post:
 *     summary: Adiciona um novo livro
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: true
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               title:
 *                 type: string
 *               author:
 *                 type: string
 *               year:
 *                 type: integer
 *               price:
 *                 type: number
 *     responses:
 *       201:
 *         description: Livro adicionado com sucesso
 *       400:
 *         description: Título, autor, ano e preço são campos obrigatórios
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao salvar os dados
 */
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const { title, author, year, price } = req.body;
  if (!title || !author || !year || !price) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Título, autor, ano e preço são campos obrigatórios.' });
  }
  const newBook = { id: books.length + 1, title, author, year, price };
  books.push(newBook);

  // Salvar os dados no arquivo JSON
  fs.writeFile(booksFilePath, JSON.stringify({ books }), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Erro ao salvar os dados no arquivo JSON.', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao salvar os dados.' });
    }
    console.log('Dados salvos no arquivo JSON com sucesso.');
  });

  res.status(201).json(newBook);
});

/**
 * @swagger
 * /books/{id}:
 *   put:
 *     summary: Atualiza um livro pelo ID
 *     parameters:
 *       - in: path
 *         name: id
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: integer
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: true
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               title:
 *                 type: string
 *               author:
 *                 type: string
 *               year:
 *                 type: integer
 *               price:
 *                 type: number
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Livro atualizado com sucesso
 *       404:
 *         description: Livro não encontrado
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao atualizar o livro
 */
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { title, author, year, price } = req.body;

  const book = books.find(u => u.id === parseInt(id));
  if (!book) return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Livro não encontrado.' });

  book.title = title || book.title;
  book.author = author || book.author;
  book.year = year || book.year;
  book.price = price || book.price;

  // Salvar os dados no arquivo JSON
  fs.writeFile(booksFilePath, JSON.stringify({ books }), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Erro ao salvar os dados no arquivo JSON.', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao salvar os dados.' });
    }
    console.log('Dados salvos no arquivo JSON com sucesso.');
  });

  res.json(book);
});

/**
 * @swagger
 * /books/{id}:
 *   delete:
 *     summary: Remove um livro pelo ID
 *     parameters:
 *       - in: path
 *         name: id
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: integer
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Livro removido com sucesso
 *       404:
 *         description: Livro não encontrado
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao remover o livro
 */
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  const index = books.findIndex(u => u.id === parseInt(id));
  if (index === -1) return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Livro não encontrado.' });

  const deletedBook = books.splice(index, 1);

  // Salvar os dados no arquivo JSON
  fs.writeFile(booksFilePath, JSON.stringify({ books }), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Erro ao salvar os dados no arquivo JSON.', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao salvar os dados.' });
    }
    console.log('Dados salvos no arquivo JSON com sucesso.');
  });

  res.json(deletedBook[0]);
});

module.exports = router;

///routes/reviews.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Caminho do arquivo JSON
const reviewsFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../data/dbReviews.json');

// Função para ler os dados do arquivo JSON
const readDataFromReviews = () => {
  try {
    const fileData = fs.readFileSync(reviewsFilePath, 'utf8');
    return JSON.parse(fileData).reviews;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao ler o arquivo JSON:', error);
    return [];
  }
};

// Carregar os dados do arquivo JSON na inicialização do servidor
let reviews = readDataFromReviews();

/**
 * @swagger
 * /reviews:
 *   get:
 *     summary: Obtém todos os comentários e avaliações
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Lista de todos os comentários e avaliações
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao obter os dados
 */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json(reviews);
});

/**
 * @swagger
 * /reviews:
 *   post:
 *     summary: Cria um novo comentário e avaliação
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: true
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               userId:
 *                 type: integer
 *               bookId:
 *                 type: integer
 *               comment:
 *                 type: string
 *               rating:
 *                 type: number
 *     responses:
 *       201:
 *         description: Comentário e avaliação criados com sucesso
 *       400:
 *         description: Dados inválidos fornecidos
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao salvar os dados
 */
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const { userId, bookId, comment, rating } = req.body;
  if (!userId || !bookId || !comment || !rating) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Dados inválidos fornecidos.' });
  }

  const newReview = { id: reviews.length + 1, userId, bookId, comment, rating };
  reviews.push(newReview);

  // Salvar os dados no arquivo JSON
  fs.writeFile(reviewsFilePath, JSON.stringify({ reviews }), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Erro ao salvar os dados no arquivo JSON.', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao salvar os dados.' });
    }
    console.log('Dados salvos no arquivo JSON com sucesso.');
  });

  res.status(201).json(newReview);
});

/**
 * @swagger
 * /reviews/book/:bookId:
 *   get:
 *     summary: Obtém todos os comentários e avaliações de um livro específico
 *     parameters:
 *       - in: path
 *         name: bookId
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: integer
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Lista de comentários e avaliações do livro
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao obter os dados
 */
router.get('/book/:bookId', (req, res) => {
  const { bookId } = req.params;
  const reviewsOfBook = reviews.filter((review) => review.bookId === parseInt(bookId));
  res.json(reviewsOfBook);
});

/**
 * @swagger
 * /reviews/user/:userId:
 *   get:
 *     summary: Obtém todos os comentários e avaliações feitos por um usuário específico
 *     parameters:
 *       - in: path
 *         name: userId
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: integer
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Lista de comentários e avaliações feitos pelo usuário
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao obter os dados
 */
router.get('/user/:userId', (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;
  const reviewsByUser = reviews.filter((review) => review.userId === parseInt(userId));
  res.json(reviewsByUser);
});

/**
 * @swagger
 * /reviews/:reviewId:
 *   put:
 *     summary: Atualiza um comentário e avaliação existente
 *     parameters:
 *       - in: path
 *         name: reviewId
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: integer
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: true
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               comment:
 *                 type: string
 *               rating:
 *                 type: number
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Comentário e avaliação atualizados com sucesso
 *       400:
 *         description: Dados inválidos fornecidos
 *       404:
 *         description: Comentário e avaliação não encontrados
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao atualizar os dados
 */
router.put('/:reviewId', (req, res) => {
  const { reviewId } = req.params;
  const { comment, rating } = req.body;

  const review = reviews.find((r) => r.id === parseInt(reviewId));
  if (!review) return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Comentário e avaliação não encontrados.' });

  review.comment = comment || review.comment;
  review.rating = rating || review.rating;

  // Salvar os dados no arquivo JSON
  fs.writeFile(reviewsFilePath, JSON.stringify({ reviews }), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Erro ao salvar os dados no arquivo JSON.', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao salvar os dados.' });
    }
    console.log('Dados salvos no arquivo JSON com sucesso.');
  });

  res.json(review);
});

/**
 * @swagger
 * /reviews/:reviewId:
 *   delete:
 *     summary: Exclui um comentário e avaliação existente
 *     parameters:
 *       - in: path
 *         name: reviewId
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: integer
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Comentário e avaliação excluídos com sucesso
 *       404:
 *         description: Comentário e avaliação não encontrados
 *       500:
 *         description: Erro ao excluir os dados
 */
router.delete('/:reviewId', (req, res) => {
  const { reviewId } = req.params;

  const index = reviews.findIndex((r) => r.id === parseInt(reviewId));
  if (index === -1) return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Comentário e avaliação não encontrados.' });

  const deletedReview = reviews.splice(index, 1);

  // Salvar os dados no arquivo JSON
  fs.writeFile(reviewsFilePath, JSON.stringify({ reviews }), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Erro ao salvar os dados no arquivo JSON.', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao salvar os dados.' });
    }
    console.log('Dados salvos no arquivo JSON com sucesso.');
  });

  res.json(deletedReview[0]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Por favor não duplique publicações, prossiga seguindo as orientações de como melhorar a publicação explicado na [postagem original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/585220/erro-com-swagger-ui-ao-implementar-em-api-node-js-apenas-opera%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-review-j#comment1020751_585220). O campo de comentários aqui será desativado para que continue na publicação original. Agradecemos a compreensão.